# Is there a way to add an alternative fix in Gerrit?

Tags: gerrit

Right now, I am committing the changes for a bug fix (ticket), and then do a

```
git push origin HEAD:refs/for/master
```

and then go through the code review on Gerrit.  If a coworker proposed a totally different fix, is there a way to try this alternative fix somehow as the same Gerrit code review but as an "alternative way"?

I thought of using this way:

1. do a `git log` to look at the commit number exactly before the commit
2. `git checkout` that commit
3. `git checkout -b ticket-1234-alternative` to start another branch and try the alternative fix

So this method starts from how the project was when you make the fix, and then lets you do an alternative fix, as a separate branch.  Is there a way that might not involve creating a different branch but using the same branch and possibly associate it with the same Gerrit code review?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to try a different fix you can choose one of the following:

1) You can amend your original commit (git commit --amend) and push the new commit as the patchset2 to the same change. If you decide to go back to the original commit you'll need to push it again as a patchset3.

2) You can make a new commit based in the parent commit (as you have suggested) and push to a new change on Gerrit. When you decide which change will be used you just need to abandon the other one.

Comment: that seems right, I can do `git commit -a --amend` and then push again, and it becomes patch 2, with the URL becoming the original one but with a `/2` added to it.  So we can use this new URL... instead of using a new branch, to keep everything under one orginal URL but just different patches